# Compile errors caused by: Warning: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations.

Tags: generics, f#

A little explanation before I ask the question.  I have a sequence on which I want to perform a number of fold operations.  But evaluating the sequence is slow and expensive (it's iterating through a database) and (though it's not explicit here) I want to provide progressive output to the user. So I'd really like to do all the folds in one go.  Something like:

```
theSeq |> Seq.CoFold [
    line (folder1, initAcc1, action1)
    line (folder2, initAcc2, action2)
]
```

the `action` being something that's done with the accumulator once the fold is complete.  I'd use it something like this:

```
theSeq |> Seq.CoFold [
    line ((fun acc r -> acc+1), 0, (fun d -> printfn "%A" d)) // counter
    line ((fun acc r -> acc.Add(r), Set.empty, whatever) // uniques
]
```

I've worked out that whatever `line` is, it should be genericked based on the type of `theSeq`, but it shouldn't depend on the type of `initAcc`, or the type of the folder function itself.  So, I've come up with the following (which doesn't work):

```
module Seq =
    type 'T line (f:'State -> 'T -> 'State, a:'State, cb:'State->unit) =
        let s = ref a
        member x.incr (j:'T) = s := f !s j
        member x.cb = cb !s

    let CoFold (folders: 'T line list) (jj: 'T seq) =
        for j in jj do
            folders |> List.iter (fun o -> o.incr j)
        folders |> List.iter (fun o -> o.cb)
```

The problem with this is that it wants to generic `line` based on both `'T` and `'State`, and that means that the two lines I've shown above are incompatible with each other, even though neither ever exposes the type of `acc`.

I've tried several other approaches (e.g. making line into a discriminated union, making line into an abstract base class, and more), and in every case I run into some other manifestation of the original problem.  I'm really at a loss to know where to look next.

This doesn't feel like it should be a difficult problem, but I guess I've got a blind spot somewhere.  Any hints gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `CoFold` doesn't really care for `line` *itself*, it only cares for `incr` and `cb`, and those are only generic in `'T`, not `'State`. So don't give it `line` itself, give it only `incr` and `cb`.

```
type 'T line = ('T -> unit) * (unit -> unit)

let makeLine incr a cb: line<_> =
  let s = ref a
  let incr' t = s := incr !s t
  let cb' () = cb !s
  incr', cb'

let CoFold (folders: 'T line list) (jj: 'T seq) =
  for j in jj do
      folders |> List.iter (fun (incr,_) -> incr j)
  folders |> List.iter (fun (_,cb) -> cb() )

aSeq |> Seq.CoFold [
  makeLine f1 s1 a1
  makeLine f2 s2 a2 ]
```

If you want to get philosophical, the root of the problem is in *complecting* `incr` and `cb`, bundling them together, when they clearly don't have to be. This is a good rule of thumb in general: keep things small and separate as much as you can.
And if you look closely, you'll see that "classes" (or "objects") are exactly this: a means of *complecting* multiple data with multiple functions. Try to avoid using classes as much as possible.

Comment: Awesome reply!  Thank you very much.  You've totally solved my problem.  But - more than that - although I already knew everything I needed to solve this, I'd never have got there on my own. Yes, I did have a blind spot. And I can see how this is going to simplify a bunch of other problems I've got.  Thanks again.